# Webpacker on Rails for producing widget.js with static URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I am working on building a JS widget for websites and this widget should have static url - e.g. `https://myproduct.com/widget.js` and I want to use ES6 power in it .. (I would somehow like to put compiled JS into `public/widget.js`)

Webpacker compiles the code into something like `http://localhost:3000/packs/js/widget-94e8fa5b2be40540f2fb.js` which doesn't play well in my case.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After compilation webpacker creates `public/packs/manifest.json` with information on how exact files are named.

In controller you can get info from manifest and redirect:

```
# get 'widget', to: 'some_controller#widget'
def widget 
  path = helpers.current_webpacker_instance.manifest.lookup!('widget', type: :javascript) # => "/packs/js/widget-94e8fa5b2be40540f2fb.js"
  redirect_to path
  # also here you can calculate path and use send_data
end
```

If you do not care about cache-busting (or employ other method), do not want additional redirect, want to serve the widget by webserver without hitting rails etc., you can copy the pack after compilation, define a rake task:

```rb
task 'copy_my_widget' => :environment do
  manifest = JSON.parse(File.read(Rails.root.join('public/packs/manifest.json')))
  pack_path = Rails.root.join('public', '.' + manifest['widget.js'])
  FileUtils.cp(pack_path, Rails.root.join('public', 'widget.js'))
end

Rake::Task["webpacker:compile"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["copy_my_widget"].invoke
end
```